# My adapter is not waiting for my onResponse, how do I fix this?

Tags: android, json, multithreading, request

I am trying to get the number of "replies" or length of a response from the network here is my request below.

```
public class Replies {
private String questionId;
private VolleySingleton mVolleySingleton;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
public int replies;


private String url;

//Predondition:Place the id of the questions into the constructor
//as well as the url
//Postcondition: counts the number of replies
public Replies(String questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
    JsonRequestMethod();
}
public void JsonRequestMethod() {
    url = "sampleURl"
    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
           replies=response.length();
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);

        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);

}
public String getReplies() {
    return replies+"";
}
```

}
Also, in my adapter i have in my on bindviewholder this line of code

```
  Replies replies=new Replies(currentSearch.getId());
    holder.replies.setText(replies.getReplies());
```

However, it keeps getting set to 0 because its not waiting for the response, and the response is not 0. How do i fix this?

Comment: Check this guide on Volley Requests and see if anything is missing -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can

```
public class Replies {

    ...

    private NetWorkFinishListener listener;


    void setListener(NetWorkFinishListener listener){

        this.listener = listener;

    }

    public interface NetWorkFinishListener{

        void onSuccess(int replies);

        void onFailed(VolleyError error);
    }

    JsonArrayRequest request = new    JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, (String) null, new       Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            replies=response.length();
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onSuccess(replies);
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onFailed(error);
            }

        }
});


}
```

And

```
Replies replies=new Replies(currentSearch.getId());
replies.setListener(new NetWorkFinishListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int replies) {
            holder.replies.setText(replies.getReplies());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(VolleyError error) {
            // do some thing
        }
    });
//holder.replies.setText(replies.getReplies());
```

But there is a bug.

Holder may not be the original.But the listener still run Success().

you can use view.setTag() to judge.